# Active MQ in Spring MVC application throws error in JBoss deployment

Tags: java, spring, jboss, activemq-classic

I am trying to use ActiveMQ in my spring web application and it works fine in tomcat 7. When I try to deploy the same in jboss, I am facing a weird exception like

```
INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS011401: Read persistence.xml for activemq
ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-5) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.module.service."deployment.message.war".main: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.module.service."deployment.message.war".main: JBAS018759: Failed to load module: deployment.message.war:main
    at org.jboss.as.server.moduleservice.ModuleLoadService.start(ModuleLoadService.java:91) [jboss-as-server-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
-
-
Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: org.jboss.as.jpa.openjpa:main
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.addPaths(Module.java:1030) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
```

Following is my context.xml

```
<bean id="jmsFactory" class="com.sample.config.CustomActiveMqConnectionFactory">
<property name="brokerURL" value="failover:(tcp://localhost:61616)?randomize=true" />
    <property name="userName" value="admin" />
    <property name="password" value="admin" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="producerJmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
        <property name="connectionFactory">
            <bean class="org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory">
                <property name="targetConnectionFactory" ref="jmsFactory" />
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
<!-- ActiveMQ destinations to use -->
    <bean id="destination" class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue"
        autowire="constructor">
        <constructor-arg value="sampleMQ" />
    </bean>



    <bean id="jmsMessageProducer" class="com.sample.service.MessageProducer">
        <property name="template" ref="producerJmsTemplate" />
        <property name="destination" ref="destination" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="messageListener" class="com.sample.service.MessageListener" />


    <bean id="jmsContainer" class="com.sample.service.CustomMessageListenerContainer">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsFactory" />
        <property name="destination" ref="destination" />
        <property name="messageListener" ref="messageListener" />
    </bean>
```

. 
My POM.Xml has the following dependencies

```
<dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
       <artifactId>activemq-core</artifactId>
       <version>5.7.0</version>
      </dependency>
     <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
      <artifactId>activemq-all</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-jpa-store</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.jboss.as</groupId>
     <artifactId>jboss-as-jpa-openjpa</artifactId>
     <version>7.2.0.Final</version>
     <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
```

Initially POM file did not have an entry of jboss-as-jpa-openjpa dependency. Even after adding it explicitly I am facing the error above. I couldnt understand the link between open jpa and activemQ. Let me know if any info is to be added up in the question. Please help me out. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

can you try putting

```
<property name="openjpa.MetaDataFactory" value="jpa"/>
```

into your persistance.xml properties section

See this for more - https://community.jboss.org/thread/231784?_sscc=t